# R: Put Variables from .GlobalEnv, that meet certain criteria in list

Tags: r, list, workspace

For some weeks I measured data once a week. Since the measuring instrument was used elsewhere in between I now got quite a few `.csv`-Files that I read into R and got them in my workspace now. I named them alike so that all of the `data.frames` contain the pattern "11." in their variable name. I know I can get a list of (only) those variable names by using

```
ls(pattern = "11.")
```

But I want to have a `list` containing those `data.frames`. Of course I could go back in my script and change the `read.table` command from e.g.

```
A.11.01 <- read.table(...)
```

to

```
data.list[1] <- read.table(...)
```

and later change the name of the list element `data.list[1]` to "A.11.01" (and would have saved a nice amount of time if I had done this immediately) and I'm quite sure I could also find out how to do this defining and naming of a list element in only one command, but it feels as if there is quite a simple option to let R create this list at all.

(Another approach I tried was `data.list[1] <- .GlobalEnv[1]`, but I ended up finding no way to subset an `environment`. (My other approaches seem too silly to be mentioned at all.))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use

```
mylist <- mget(ls(pattern = "11."))
```

or, if you want to make sure that you only get `data.frame`s with that pattern (not other objects) you could use

```
mylist <- Filter(is.data.frame, mget(ls(pattern = "11.")))
```

---

By the way, in your situation, it would have been easy to read them into a list directly using something like

```
listfiles <- list.files("path/to/folder", pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names=TRUE)
mylist <- lapply(listfiles, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

(`stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is just an example to show you that you can easily add other arguments)

Comment: Btw special thanks for the trick for reading in several tables in a list at one time!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways, computer time is cheaper than human time, so it might be wiser to use `lapply` on a vector of file names as suggested by `docendo discimus`.

But then again, it's easy to convert your .GlobalEnv to a list and then subset it, say, using `grep`:

```
gelist <- as.list(.GlobalEnv)
# or ... as.list(environment())
gelist <- gelist[grep("^11\\.", names(gelist))]
# ^ saying that expected pattern is at the beginning of the string
# and . has a special meaning for grep, so it has to be "escaped" by \\
# see ?regexp
```